What is stim and what are its use
What exactly is this stim? https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim?tab=readme-ov-file#what-is-stim
It would be really great if someone can explain about stim.

Do you have a specific question? You linked a doc that appears to answer your question

Thank you @xzkxyz for the response. My question is whether it is some kind simulator or some kind of new framework. Is it something related to googleAI or Cirq? I saw a lot about it being mentioned in https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-022-05434-1   https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.6804040.    Trying to understand this paper?
